# Camel Http4 using basic auth and proxy auth

Tags: java, apache-camel, proxy-authentication, camel-http

I've been trying to use Apache Camel's Http4 component to connect to a HTTPS URL that needs Basic authentication. The connection needs to be done through an authenticated HTTP proxy.

So, according to the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html), I configure the Camel endpoint like this:

```
.toD("https4://target.host/resource?
        bridgeEndpoint=true
        &mapHttpMessageBody=false

        &proxyAuthHost=my.proxy.host
        &proxyAuthPort=myProxyPort
        &proxyAuthUsername=proxyUser
        &proxyAuthPassword=proxyPassword
        &proxyAuthScheme=http4

        &authenticationPreemptive=true
        &authUsername=myUser
        &authPassword=myPassword")
```

Which results in a `403 - Forbidden` response from the target server. Looking through the `org.apache.http.wire` logs, it shows that the proxy credentials *proxyUser* / *proxyPassword* are forwarded to the target server instead of the intended *myUser*/*myPassword* in the `Authorization` header.

Debugging the source for [`CompositeHTTPConfigurer.configureHttpClient`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/CompositeHttpConfigurer.java#38), [`ProxyHttpClientConfigurer.configureHttpClient`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/ProxyHttpClientConfigurer.java#54) and [`BasicAuthenticationHttpClientConfigurer.configureHttpClient`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/BasicAuthenticationHttpClientConfigurer.java#39), it seems that because both configurers are setting their credentials to the `HttpClientBuilder` by means of `setDefaultCredentialsProvider`, one of them is lost - gets overwritten - in the process.

Looks like it could be a bug in Camel's Http4 component? Or am I missing something?

This is Camel 2.18.2 with Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After raising this question on the [Apache Camel Users list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Http4-using-basic-auth-and-proxy-auth-td5794971.html), it seems the bug is confirmed.

I solved it using `camel-http` instead of `camel-http4`. Endpoint parameters needed a slight tweaking:

```
.toD("https://target.host/resource?
    bridgeEndpoint=true

    &proxyHost=my.proxy.host
    &proxyPort=myProxyPort
    &proxyAuthUsername=proxyUser
    &proxyAuthPassword=proxyPassword
    &proxyAuthMethod=Basic

    &authUsername=myUser
    &authPassword=myPassword
    &authMethod=Basic
    &httpClient.authenticationPreemptive=true")
```